# How to go to the next page in Novacode Docx

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I am using Novacode DocX in C#. Using method `InsertSectionPageBreak()`. But it does not save the parameters of the default page. For example page should be in landscape format. When using `InsertSectionPageBreak()` the format changes to the book. I need that each table has been on every page with landscape format.

```
using (DocX doc = DocX.Create(fileName))
{
     doc.PageLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;
     var table = doc.AddTable(12, 2); 
     doc.InsertTable(table);
     doc.InsertSectionPageBreak();                           
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Any code to show?  This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using the `InsertSectionPageBreak` method of the `DocX` class, use the `InsertPageBreakAfterSelf` of the `Table` class.

```
doc.InsertTable(table).InsertPageBreakAfterSelf();
```

It should keep the style from the previous page.

Comment: Using the section break method was causing the page size to revert to 'Letter' for subsequent sections. Using this method avoided this issue. Thanks!